# Find $n$ integers from $3n$ ones

Tags: combinatorics, integers

$n$ is a positive integer. Is the following statement true?

For any $3n$ integers, saying $\{b_1,..,b_{3n}\}$. There exists $n$ of them, saying $\{a_1,..,a_n\}$,so that $\forall$ $1\leq i,j,k\leq n$ we have $a_i+a_j\neq a_k$. Here $i,j,k$ is not necessary to be different.

I tried to mod them by $3$ and use Principle of tolerance, but it does not help when most of them divided by $3$. I also get some easy inequality by considering some possible trivial condition, for example if $b_l$ are ranked from small to big, if $2b_m\geq b_{m+n}$ for some $m$. I can take $\{b_m,..,b_{m+n-1}\}$ as desired.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No. If $0 \in \{b_1,\dots,b_{3n}\}$, then it certainly doesn't hold, because $0+a_j = a_j$. The question might be more interesting if you either disallow $0$, so $b_1,\dots,b_n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ or require $i,j,k$ to be all different.

Comment: The problem in essence seems to be very similar to the [Zero-sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_problem), which is solved by the Erdős-Ginzburg-Ziv theorem. It says that out of $2n-1$ integers in $\mathbb{Z}$, you can always choose $n$ of them, such that their sum is divisible by $n$.